# Is there a way to set the default mouse cursor image for a java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working with a large java swing application.   The customer wants to have a larger cursor image for the mouse because of the limitations (space) of the monitors that can be used for the application.

The way to do this for a single Swing JFrame instance is something like:

`Image image = toolkit.getImage("resources/NetworkGreen48.gif");
Cursor customCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image , new Point(0, 8), "img");
mainJFrame.setCursor (customCursor);`

this works fine for the mainJFrame JFrame and any components embedded on the mainJFrame JFrame.

However, this application has literally hundreds of independent JFrames, JDialogs, etc.  For these, running in the same JVM, but not actively added to the mainJFrame JFrame, the cursor reverts to the operating system default.

Is there a good way to set the mouse cursor for ALL the places the mouse will be used in the Swing application?

Considered doing it by talking to the OS, but, this application is running on Windows currently and will run on some version of linux in the future so I'd better not depend on the OS.

I can do this on a Frame by Frame basis.  Would just like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

first part : custom cursor
I was searching to define this using look and feel but i didn't find anything about loding custom cursor inside, so there is 2 solution always use a custom sub class of JFrame where the method frameInit is override to use your cursor. Or use a factory to create all the frame you need to set the property as you do before.

Swing is not completely os independant i think that you see few rendering difference between the os you use. The only think that change is the look and feel(laf or plaf), each OS use its own plaf. but there is a cross OS Laf call Metal. Here is the documentation related to how change laf :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

to be sure to be cross OS its recommanded to work using Metal but it's not required.

Comment: Thank you, Arnault.  Subclassing is not possible do to the amount of code.  Factory is a possibility.